# Php use a class in the constructor of another class and require it with namespace

Tags: php, oop, composer-php

I have som legacy code that broke after an update of a dependency class of my ex colleague's Handler class of the [Cosenary Instagram Class](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API) using composer.

The former reference to include the class in the handler class was this:

```
namespace Acme\Instagram;
class Handler
{ 

/* GOT SOME USEFUL VARS HERE */

const API_URL = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1';

/**
 * Initialize the library
 *
 * @param array  $settings Contains our ClientId and upload dir
 * @param string $root_dir The root of our application
 */
public function __construct( $settings, $root_dir = __DIR__ )
{
    include_once  $root_dir . '/vendor/cosenary/instagram/instagram.class.php'; //HERE WAS THE INCLUDE BEFORE


    // THROW SOME EXCEPTIONS HERE IF SETTINGS MISSING ETC...

    // New instance of the instagram class
    $this->_instagram = new \Instagram($this->_clientId);
}

/* HANDLE SOM FUNCTIONS HERE */

}
```

And if I change the include_once to:

```
    require_once $root_dir . '/vendor/cosenary/instagram/src/Instagram.php';
```

Then I get:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Acme\Instagram\Instagram' not found in
```

I guess I need to pass it in as a reference in the constructor but that means I need to rewrite a lot of code and there is probably 5-10 other projects that is depending on this Hanlder class. Is there a way to use the instagram class in this other class?

Tried moving out the include_once and:

```
use MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram;
```

But no luck, any help or pointers i greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how is Your app's structure looks.
But try this:

```
namespace Acme\Instagram;

require_once $root_dir.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram AS InstagramClient;

class Handler
{ 

/* GOT SOME USEFUL VARS HERE */

const API_URL = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1';

/**
 * Initialize the library
 *
 * @param array  $settings Contains our ClientId and upload dir
 * @param string $root_dir The root of our application
 */
public function __construct( $settings, $root_dir = __DIR__ )
{
    // New instance of the instagram class
    $this->_instagram = new InstagramClient($this->_clientId);
}

/* HANDLE SOM FUNCTIONS HERE */
```

Comment: I get Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script in... If I use it before the namespace declaration.

Comment: Nice, got it working again. With some other issues though. But seems to be another problem. Thanks!